# How to create a vertical menu that slides up and down?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm in highschool and just starting to learn HTML, CSS, and JQuery. I know how to make the individual items on my list slide into view, but I'm not sure how to make them slide back up and disappear once the items are clicked a second time. Here's my code so far:

```
.drop {
    width:200px;
    background-color:#000;
    padding:5px;
}
    .drop > p {
        color:white;
        text-align:center;
    }
.slide {
    display:none;
    width:180px;
    background-color:#fff;
    padding:5px;
    margin:auto;
}
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="drop inactive"> 
            <p>00/00/00</p>
            <div class="slide article-preview">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin at nulla sed nisi tempus fringilla. Duis lorem eros, pharetra vel luctus at, gravida vel nisi. Aliquam tincidunt diam nec quam blandit elementum. Nunc imperdiet risus non interdum vestibulum. Aenean tempus, turpis sit amet laoreet suscipit, nunc erat elementum metus, sed tincidunt ipsum nisl eu dui. Integer erat turpis, posuere vel sapien quis, cursus molestie ante. Morbi maximus odio nec odio pulvinar, vel porta quam maximus.
            <a href=#>Read more...</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="drop inactive">
            <p>00/00/00</p>
            <div class="slide article-preview">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin at nulla sed nisi tempus fringilla. Duis lorem eros, pharetra vel luctus at, gravida vel nisi. Aliquam tincidunt diam nec quam blandit elementum. Nunc imperdiet risus non interdum vestibulum. Aenean tempus, turpis sit amet laoreet suscipit, nunc erat elementum metus, sed tincidunt ipsum nisl eu dui. Integer erat turpis, posuere vel sapien quis, cursus molestie ante. Morbi maximus odio nec odio pulvinar, vel porta quam maximus.
            <a href=#>Read more...</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="drop inactive">
            <p>00/00/00</p>
            <div class="slide article-preview">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin at nulla sed nisi tempus fringilla. Duis lorem eros, pharetra vel luctus at, gravida vel nisi. Aliquam tincidunt diam nec quam blandit elementum. Nunc imperdiet risus non interdum vestibulum. Aenean tempus, turpis sit amet laoreet suscipit, nunc erat elementum metus, sed tincidunt ipsum nisl eu dui. Integer erat turpis, posuere vel sapien quis, cursus molestie ante. Morbi maximus odio nec odio pulvinar, vel porta quam maximus.
            <a href=#>Read more...</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(".inactive").click(function(){
                $(".slide").slideUp('slow');
                $(this).children().slideDown("slow");
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please create jsfiddle example. You can use this link: https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Thank you! I've got it working now.

Comment: you are doing a good job with using .click , $(this) , children() , slideUp()  and slideDown() .. so you have a good knowledge about jquery .. I recommend this jquery tutorials it will helpful https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GNb8T5NBdQg&list=PL6B08BAA57B5C7810  .. Good Luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Heres a fiddle  with different toggle options. It uses the slideToggle function in jquery to show/hide the specified element. setting a number instead of the string "slow" like (700) runs the slide function over 700 milliseconds:

```
$(this).find(".slide").slideToggle("slow");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/agbb7n61/1/